# How to find out whether a field level security is assigned through permission set or profile

Tags: soql, profile, permission-sets, field-level-security

I want to know whether the field level security is assigned through profile or permission set through SOQL.

Comment: if field is accessible and profile does not have it set then it has to be via perm set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be assigned through both (they can overlap), but you can generally find out by performing a query:

```
SELECT PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE Field = 'Account.Industry' AND
      Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE
      AND ParentId IN 
         (SELECT PermissionSetId 
          FROM PermissionSetAssignment
          WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

You can change the fields or queries in a variety of interesting ways, depending on exactly what you're trying to find out.

Comment: Why I'm getting unknown error parsing query. I'm unable to get this query work.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou This has to be done in Apex. If you're using straight SOQL, you need to somehow retrieve the user Id first and plug that in to your query.